# Error loading TensorflowJS in Electron App (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, electron, tensorflow.js

I am trying to get tensorflow working in my electron app using tensorflow js.

Here are the details of the various versions:

Nodejs: v14.4.0
@tensorflow/tfjs - 2.0.0
@tensorflow/tfjs-node - 2.0.0
electron - 1.8.8

When I try to load the tfjs module using:

> const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

I get the following error:
[image]

I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find anything relevant for this error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please downgrade to node 10 or 12 and see if the issue still occurs ?

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for responding. I started off with 8.10 then 12.8 and then 14.4. I saw the documentation for v14.4 and see that util.Encoder is present. https://nodejs.org/api/util.html

Perhaps I should clear out the node_modules folder and try again?

Comment: And what is the result after trying ?

Comment: So I just renamed the node_modules directory to node_modules_orig and did

`npm install electron`

It installed all the modules including tensorFlow. I still got the same error.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure that only loading `@tensorflow/tfjs` causes the error ?

Comment: Yes. When I comment that line out, no problems.

I looked into that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215380/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-arun-krishnan).

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

The issue seems to be one of competing libraries. Although I don't know exact which library, found a workaround which involved installing @tensorflow/tfjs first followed by all other libraries.

Thanks to @edkeveked for all his help.

The solution is to

1. Create a new electron project
2. Install electron followed by @tensorflow/tfjs
3. Install all other required modules
4. Move the node_modules directory from this to my original app directoy.

Hope this helps someone else facing this issue.